# How can I create plain text instead as variable of html text with php?

Tags: php, html

I would like to create variable as plain text from html text. For example I wanted to take output title instead of text between h1 tag with HTML2TEXT.php library. But I have problem with take output bold, h1 values. Is there any way to do it? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

```html
include 'Html2Text.php';

$html = "<p><b>without</b> using htmlspecialchars() function</p>";
$html2Text = new Html2Text($html);
    
echo $html2Text->getText();
```

Comment: Please show an example of a situation that is causing you problems. The inputs and the outputs

Comment: I am taking output like 'WITHOUT using htmlspecialchars() function'. And Without should be bold.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the word `without` to be Bolded as text because it was wrapped in `<b></b>` tags in HTML?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: No! There is no concept of BOLD in plain text. You need some kind of markup to be able to do things like that.... For example **HTML** or **RTF** or ..... But text is just simple character byte streams